# Cerberus schema with single dict or list of dicts

Tags: python, cerberus

I'm trying to build a schema where the statement can be a single dict or a list of dicts. Ex:

`{'Document': {'key': 'value'}}`

Or multiple keys:

`{'Document': [ {'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]}`

Following the documentation I tested with this schema:

`v.schema = {'Document': {'type': ['dict', 'list'], 'schema': {'type': 'dict'}}}`

Here is the output:

```
>>> v.schema = {'Document': {'type': ['dict', 'list'], 'schema': {'type': 'dict'}}}
>>> v.validate({'Document': [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]})
True
>>> v.validate({'Document': {'key': 'value'} })
False
>>> v.errors
{'Document': ['must be of dict type']}
```

Test code:

```
import cerberus

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = cerberus.Validator()
    v.schema = {'Document': {'type': ['dict', 'list'], 'schema': {'type': 'dict'}}}
    print(v.validate({'Document': [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]}))
    print(v.validate({'Document': {'key': 'value'}}))
    print(v.errors)
```

The second case the value is a dict type but I get this error instead of getting the schema correctly interpreted.

Comment: Can you extend the code snippet and show how you defined 'v'?

Comment: Updated the question with a full test code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the schema-rule and mapping, if you remove the schema rule it should work like this:

```
import cerberus

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = cerberus.Validator()
    v.schema = {'Document': {'type': ['dict', 'list']}}
    print(v.validate({'Document': [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]}))
    print(v.validate({'Document': {'key': 'value'}}))
    print(v.errors)
```

More info about schema-rule and mapping:

https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#schema-dict

Comment: Hi Jayvee,

The trick is that I want to apply a schema to the dict too. So, the solution that you propose works but just don't validate the dict has a schema that I want to apply.